# Firebase Admin SDK from the CDN

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

In my Firestore project I use CDN to import like:

```
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  doc,
  setDoc,
  addDoc
} from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.18.0/firebase-firestore.js';
```

And it works well. Now I would like to start working with Firebase Admin SDK, but I can't find CDN for it. Could you give me a link please?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase SDK is meant to be used on server side only and hence there is no CDN link for it. 
It also requires a service account to be initialized in a non Google environmemt and exposing it to the public will grant complete access to your resources to everyone.

Checkout the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on setting up Admin SDK and [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Functions%20for%20Firebase%20is,runs%20in%20a%20managed%20environment.) to execute your server side code.

Comment: I tried to install in root and public and still the error: Uncaught TypeError: The specifier “firebase-admin/app” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.

Comment: @awariat that does not seem to relate with your original question and you have not provided any details on where are your running these commands, whether it is in cloud function dir or os.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to use it in file which is in "public/js" folder in my project. I work in Visual Studio code and test using http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin-users.html (example file). All Firestore imports I have from CDN. I am using "firebase deploy" to upload to google servers. In which directory should i use "npm install firebase-admin --save"?